# Runtime error on AWS, but code runs in Jupyter Notebook without errors

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, runtime-error

I am building an automated investment bot using the simple moving average and the TD Ameritrade API. The bot has run successfully on a schedule locally using crontab, but the same code in AWS Lambda returns a runtime error and is maxed out at a 15 minute runtime. I'm not too sure how to troubleshoot this in AWS... so i guess my question is, is there a different syntax in AWS Lambda for Python that I should be aware of?

I understand that this is sort of broad without a copy of the code itself, but it contains a lot of account sensitive information that I can't share. Are there any general tips for troubleshooting AWS runtime errors?

Comment: You can remove the sensitive information and replace it with something along the lines of "{SECRET_KEY}".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.